# How to have faith and devotion again?

Tags: bhakti, prayer

I have become attached to all forbidden things rather than praying and worshiping.

How do I free myself of all hindrances to my faith and devotion?

Comment: You must ask yourself as a first step  why do you want to devote to something?

Comment: Devotion to lord bring bliss and motivation... but what happens when you attached him with forbidden things like lust,greed and all